# How to share an app for instant view/execute on an emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, share

I would like to know is it possible to package my android app files, so that another person can download online and simply open an emulator in order to view and test my working app.

I want to make it as straight forward as possible for my app to be viewable to a non-coder (without uploading the app on Google play store)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ideally I am looking for solutions that don't involve preparation before opening the app. i.e installing via terminal, or having a certain app installed to view this app.  I need to get this app marked by my professor, who will have many other projects to look at.

Comment: Hi Dylan, thank you for asking. It's a month before I've to submit, still not found a perfect solution yet (I assume it doesn't exist in this case!) as they all need pre-preparation & not instantaneous.. but when the time comes I will try out the options such as Deploygate etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst it doesn't cover off on the users that don't have Android phones, [DeployGate](https://deploygate.com/) is a pretty nice option for allowing users to check out your app without uploading to the app store.

You just upload your app and send the link to your 'testers'. If they have the deploygate app they can easily download your app to their phone and give it a go!

Comment: I assume if supposedly I implemented google play service (not sure how that works) I won't be able to carry out such testing?

Comment: Yeah you could use the Google play store. They have a mechanism where you add people to a Google+ group and only the people in that group will have access to see your app on the app store. I think they have an Alpha and a Beta test group... This has the advantage of testing your deployment to the store as well, without giving everyone free access to your app!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an apk and share it via Google Drive or Dropbox.

The other person can download that and install in their phone.

In order to see your app in emulator, he/she will have to install it via Terminal with the following command:

```
adb install path_to_your.apk
```